# How redirect requests to another domain name without changing the website URL?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, domain-name

I have a web site `exemple.com` and another named `dummy.com`. The two of them point to the same server.
What I want is that the home page of `dummy.com` show, in reality, `exemple.com/dummy` but I don't want the URL `dummy.com` to change so I can't use redirection as far as I know it.
I heard reverse-proxy can do that but I don't know the way. If it can't, is there a way to achieve what I want ?
I use apache2 as the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this quite easily with Apache2 as a reverse proxy. First of all, you need to install and enable the mod_proxy module. Then you need to update your vSite configuration, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dummy.com

        ProxyPass "/"  "http://exemple.com/dummy/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://exemple.com/dummy/"

        DocumentRoot /var/www/dummy.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally restart apache so your changes are effective.

Best regards 
Andreas

Comment: thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that I could help :-)